# What's the definition of image size in OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

What's the size

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('./imgs/img.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

print(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])  # 182 277
print(img.size)  # 151242
```

I thought `img.size = img.width * img.width`, but obviously wrong, check this example.

so, what's the definition of it?

Comment: np.prod(img.shape) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html Im not a Python expert, but probably for an image this means width x height x channels. In C++ interface the Mat.size gives the width and height as a struct. It is all about whether you interprete an image as a 2D or a 3D array, where either one element is a pixel or one element is single number value.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely 151242 == 182 * 277 * 3 here. It's a RGB color without transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about what language you're working in.

The Python interface to OpenCV uses **`numpy`**, and numpy arrays have different methods from `cv::Mat` (C++). `size` means different things then.

- Python: OpenCV uses `numpy` arrays. `.size` tells you the number of elements in the array. That is the product of all values in `.shape`.
- C++: OpenCV uses its own `cv::Mat`. `.size` there is of type `MatSize`. It is roughly equivalent to `.shape` with numpy. Documentation indicates that it can also tell you the number of channels. It has an `operator[]` defined.